# | (or) operator for scala parsing combinators does not work

Tags: scala, parsing, integer, double, parser-combinators

The `exactIntegerLiteral` parses successfully as well as `exactDoubleLiteral`, but they do not work with the same input `-1234.4` when combined together in `ExectNumericLiteral`. What could be the cause?

```
def exactIntegerLiteral: Parser[IntegerLiteral] =
        "[-+]?\\d+(?!\\.)".r ^^ { parsed => IntegerLiteral(parsed.toLong) }

def exactDoubleLiteral: Parser[DoubleLiteral] =
        "[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?".r ^^ { parsed => DoubleLiteral(parsed.toDouble) }

def exactNumericLiteral: Parser[NumericLiteral] = 
        exactIntegerLiteral | exactDoubleLiteral
```

`|||` this method does the work, but nevertheless I don't understand the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two parsers `p` and `q`, the parser `p | q` short-circuits if `p` succeeds. Since you're defining `exactNumericLiteral` such that `exactIntegerLiteral` is tried first, it will always match on "-1234" and hence there's no need to try `exactDoubleLiteral` as well.

Switching the order of `exactIntegerLiteral` and `exactDoubleLiteral` to

```
def exactNumericLiteral: Parser[NumericLiteral] = 
        exactDoubleLiteral | exactIntegerLiteral
```

will try the double literal first and hence do what you want (or what I suppose you want, the question was a bit unclear as to what exactly doesn't work as expected).

When using `p ||| q` instead of `p | q`, both `p` and `q` will be tried and the result of the one with the longest match will be chosen. In your example, that will be `exactDoubleLiteral` when given `-1234.4`.

EDIT: According to the question below, it should be noted that it matters whether you call `parseAll` or `parse`. In case of `parseAll`, the parser is supposed to match the whole input stream which `exactIntegerLiteral` won't do for `-1234.4`. Calling `parse` instead will match until the `.` and consume no more of the input stream.

Comment: Actually, exactIntegerLiteral doesn't match, and throws exception, but it should as you said. Exception message: failure: string matching regex `\z' expected but `4' found

Comment: That's when you call `parseAll` because then your parser is supposed to match the whole input, but `exactIntegerLiteral` cannot do that. Try `parse` instead and it will match until the `.`, and the rest of the input stream remains.